# ng-file-upload's ngf-select directive causing multiple browser windows in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, ng-file-upload

I am using ng-file-upload in my project and I am facing a queer problem. In firefox, whenever I am clicking on the button, it opens up the browser window multiple times (mostly twice, faced 3 a coule of times). Also, if I select different inages in each window, they are getting uploaded. This is happening only in Firefox which is my maon dev broeser. I cant reproduce this in chrome or edge. Please help!
HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">
        <input type="text" ng-model="myActionsCtrl.title">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-8 large-8 columns">
        <input type="text" value="{{myActionsCtrl.file.name}} {{myActionsCtrl.errfile.name}} {{myActionsCtrl.errfile.error}}" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 medium-4 large-4 columns">
        <button class="button" type="file" ng-model="myActionsCtrl.image" ngf-select="myActionsCtrl.browseImage($file, $invalidFiles)"
            accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB">Browse</button>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 medium-4 large-4 columns">
        <button class="button" ng-click="myActionsCtrl.uploadImage()">Upload</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">
        <img ngf-src="myActionsCtrl.image" ngf-resize="{width: 200, height: 200, quality: 0.9}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
module.exports = function ($scope, Upload) {
    let vm = this;

    vm.uploadImage = function () {
        if (vm.file) {
            vm.file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: '/uploads/gallery',
                method: 'POST',
                data: { title: vm.title },
                file: vm.file
            });

            vm.file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    vm.file.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0) { }
                vm.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            }, function (evt) {
                vm.file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 *
                    evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }
    }

    vm.browseImage = function (file, errFiles) {
        vm.file = file;
        vm.errFile = errFiles && errFiles[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Also this problem is not reproducible always. The same bit of code which was causing this error does not seem to give the same error today. I don't know if this is a development specific problem or not. Also I am using gulp as a task runner.

Comment: If you could create a reproducible jsfiddle I would investigate. Otherwise it might be just your local setting/tools/etc.